# Show Custom Field On Woocommerce View Order Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show Air Waybill on customer 'view order' page of woocommerce
I create a custome field named AWB , value xxx

How to show them on the view order page of woocommece
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override templates->order->`order-detals.php` to edit view order page. just `print_r($item_meta);` below the `$item_meta->display();` and you will get get an array including your custom field value on view order page. Now fetch your custom field data from the array.

Or
Use this query below `$item_meta->display();`

`$pid=$item_meta->meta['_product_id'][0];

$custom_val=$wpdb->get_var("select meta_value from wp_postmeta where post_id = {$pid} AND meta_key='AWB'");
echo  "Air Waybill: ".$custom_val;`

Note: AWB =custom field name

Comment: thank you @nishant but i can't find the custom field data from that array

Answer (score 9):

Overriding order-details.php is bad practice, because when you update the woocommerce version, it resets everything you made changes in woocommerce core files. Better option is to use themes functions.php to show custom field in view orders page like this :

```
function action_woocommerce_order_details_after_customer_details($order) {

   echo get_post_meta( $order->id, 'awb', true );
}

add_action('woocommerce_order_details_after_customer_details', 'action_woocommerce_order_details_after_customer_details', 10, 1);
```